# 403 Forbidden Magento Imagies

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.9

My Media url is giving me a 403 I don't understand why I can see the product images but i can see other images like me slides. Any ideas i set the folder to 755. I've tried other methods that were posted here on stackoverflow but they don't seem to work.

Comment: Have you set the contents of the folder to 755 as well?

Comment: Have you upgrade or install any security patches?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?